# What is a convolution kernel?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convolution, markov-process

What is a convolution kernel? (in measure theory, probability theory)

In which book can I read about kernels on measurable spaces and convolution kernels?

Thank you!

Comment: [This page (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29) and [this page](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/digitalimaging/processing/kernelmaskoperation/) give a description of what I think you're talking about.  I'm not sure, though.

Comment: No. I need it for this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059768/a-problem-with-kernels-on-measurable-spaces

Comment: Revuz's "Markov chains" may have that: there were some chapters on Markov Chains on groups, hence I'd expect convolution kernels there. Check Markov Chains on groups in general.

Comment: Are you potentially referring to [kernels](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Kernel_(Measure_Theory)) in measure theory?